# MySQL - how do I force AVG function to include 0's

Tags: mysql

```
set @cumulativeSum := 0;

SELECT
    z.hour+1 as time,
    (@cumulativeSum := @cumulativeSum + z.enquiries) as target
        FROM
        (   SELECT
                    y.hour as hour,
                    IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(y.enquiries), 0), 0) as enquiries
                FROM
                     (  SELECT DAY(o.date_created),
                               HOUR(o.date_created) as hour,
                               COUNT(DISTINCT o.phone) as enquiries
                            FROM orders o
                            WHERE phone IS NOT NULL
                                    AND name NOT LIKE 'test%'
                                    AND o.email NOT LIKE 'jawor%'
                                    AND o.email NOT LIKE 'test%'
                                    AND o.email NOT LIKE '%moneyshake%'
                                    AND o.date_created < CURRENT_DATE()
                                    AND o.date_created >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -7 DAY
                            GROUP BY HOUR(o.date_created), DAY(o.date_created) ) y
                GROUP BY hour ) z
```

This query is meant to give an average number of enquiries by hour for the last 7 days. I've done it this way to exclude duplicates of `o.phone` only within each hour of each day, rather than across all days or all hours.

It outputs:

| time | target |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| etc.. | etc.. |

I want it to include a row for 4am, even if the value for target doesn't change (because the AVG for 4am is 0)

Please let me know if more info is needed!

Comment: You must generate a rowset which contains all values (time) you're interested in and use it as a base. What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina Thanks, that makes sense - will try it now. I'm using v5.7.12 :)

Comment: If so then such base table as `SELECT 0 time UNION SELECT 1 UNION ... UNION SELECT 23` is the most simple dynamic solution. Or additional static table with the numbers from 0 to 23 in your database.

Comment: @Akina I was lazy and used ```SELECT HOUR(o.date_created) +1 as hour FROM orders o WHERE o.date_created > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY GROUP BY HOUR(o.date_created)```

Comment: Imagine there is a hole for 2 hours... 3 hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Akina's comment for solving

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).